# What is the difference between 'field' and 'field.keyword'?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have imported an index into elasticsearch 6.X.X, and two types have been created with the name of field and field.keyword.

The field.keyword is aggregatable and field is not.

Both are of the string type.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

The field.keyword is the not analyzed value of your text field value while field contains all the token after the value have been analyzed.

So you can use field.keyword for your aggregation and field for your search

You can check the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/multi-fields.html).

Comment: Yes, I know that, but in kibana, in both fields it says they are of the string type, not text or keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The string type was deprecated some time ago and Elasticsearch 6.x is not backwards compatible to handle them.

How to migrate:
In most cases, the migration should be pretty straightforward. Fields that used to be mapped as an analyzed string

```
{
  "foo": {
    "type" "string",
    "index": "analyzed"
  }
}
```

Now need to be mapped as a text field:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "type" "text",
    "index": true
  }
}
```

And fields that used to be mapped as a not_analyzed string

```
{
  "foo": {
    "type" "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  }
}
```

Now need to be mapped as a keyword field:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "type" "keyword",
    "index": true
  }
}
```

See this for a full explanation:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

Comment: Yes, I know that, but in kibana, in both fields it says they are of the string type, not text or keyword.

Comment: Yes, you need to change them in the index mapping from string to text/keyword as I have described.